# Plutus Pioneer Program Week01 : Installing plutus - Unable to start server if syncing plutus with plutus-pioneer-program version

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

In the plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01 folder, I got the tag as tag: ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4

The git log tag for plutus was 9879b31579d0deb863f3cdf27f93419deec3b4bb
So I used git checkout ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4 on the plutus repository.

If I try starting the server, it does not start, giving this error after trying for a long time.

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus/git/plutus/plutus-playground-client]$ plutus-playground-server
plutus-playground-server: for development use only
warning: unable to download 'https://github.com/input-output-hk/hackage.nix/archive/6dba3997f6a39d51fe814d312b1a4b52838a8055.tar.gz': HTTP error 200 (curl error: Timeout was reached); retrying in 347 ms

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: program 'tar' failed with exit code 2
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: program 'tar' failed with exit code 2
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

Here is what I have done to try setup my environment.

1. I am on Win10.  I have git installed.
2. I chose to use the vagrant based setup.
3. Downloaded and installed Vagrant and VirtualBox (6.1). Rebooted.
4. Cloned the vagrant repository, `git clone https://github.com/edwint88/plutus-vm plutus-vm`
5. Using `git bash`, did `vagrant up`.  It reads Vagrantfile, tries to find the VM, which is not there, so downloads the VM from internet, Ubuntu website. VM has been downloaded on the Windows machine
6. ssh into the vm using `vagrant ssh`
7. Update plutus using

   ```
   cd /home/vagrant/plutus/git/plutus 
   git pull 
   update /bin/bash ../updatePlutus.sh
   ```

It updated the plutus repository and git log gives me head as
9879b31579d0deb863f3cdf27f93419deec3b4bb

8. Run nix-shell
   cd to week01 folder
   Then did
   cabal update
   cabal build
9. Checked tag in cabal.project file.  It had tag as ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4 (this is same as in Video1 of Plutus Pioneer Program - Lecture #1 in both cohorts.
10. As the tag is not same as plutus's it means we need to get an older version of plutus
11. Went to plutus dir and `git checkout ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4`
    Verified that git log now shows this tag.
12. Tried to start the server
    `cd plutus-playground-client`
    `plutus-playground-server`

It is giving the error shown.

Note, earlier when I did not understand I had to update the plutus repo to match, I had tried starting the server, and it came up successfully.

Comment: unable to download - this error indicates that there might be an issue with the Internet connection and the tar is broken. Kindly check it again.

Comment: Quite possibly.  As now, when I am trying to do nix-shell, it is failing to untar this same tar  file (as it must have got partially downloaded last time).  How to retrigger the redownload this file.

Comment: I tried ``` /bin/bash ../updatePlutus.sh```.  Still it is giving same error.  unpacking 'https://github.com/input-output-hk/hackage.nix/archive/6dba3997f6a39d51fe814d312b1a4b52838a8055.tar.gz'...

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: program 'tar' failed with exit code 2
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)

Comment: I finally did the entire installation again,  Cleaned up the vagrant VM and redid the steps. Able to compile EnglishAuction.hs in the playground!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post the steps as answer. It will help other.